# Convert string type number to int number and sum up in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have below XML,

```
    <Answers>
     <Entry key="total" type="System.String">
      <value>50,000</value>
     </Entry>
    </Answers>
    <Answers>
     <Entry key="total" type="System.String">
      <value>2,000</value>
     </Entry>
    </Answers>
    <PerPersonTotal>1000</PerPersonTotal>
```

In XSLT 1.0 i have to sum up all the values and calculate percentage.

Note that the amount value has comma.

```
<xsl:value-of select="(PerPersonTotal div sum(number(Answers/Entry[@key='total']/value))) * 100
```

and am getting below error

> Argument 1 of function 'sum()' cannot be converted to a node-set.

if i remove number function i am getting NaN as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that the amount value has comma.

And that's exactly the problem here: a string containing a comma is not a number. To solve this in XSLT 1.0,  you will need to do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="values">
    <xsl:for-each select="Answers/Entry[@key='total']">
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(value, ',', '')"/>
        </value>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<result>
    <xsl:value-of select="PerPersonTotal div sum(exsl:node-set($values)/value)"/>
</result>
```

after declaring `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` - see: http://exslt.org/exsl/index.html

**Note:**

1. This assumes the comma here is used as a thousands separator;
2. To format a number as percentage, you should use the `format-number()`
   function, not multiply by 100.

Comment: with small change in the above code i can calculate now. Yes i am using format-number for percentage now. Thanks